# How can I read and calculate human blood pressure using camera in Android?

Tags: android, image, video, camera, google-mlkit

I am looking into understanding if an **Android phone camera** has the capability to detect **blood pressure** in humans using video(short) or images. Went through the **[Google Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision)** and **[ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection)** but couldn't find appropriate solutions.

So I would like to know if there is any solution in Android to **read and calculate** human blood pressure using camera. Any logic, doc, or app link will be helpful.

Comment: Can you do that by looking at a person?  No?  Then why would you think a video could?

Comment: So @GabeSechan does that mean it is totally not possible with existing apis?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't do this with the camera phone because it can't do this, if you saw some samsung devices do this, this is because it has a special sensores.

**Phone has a special sensors:**

[image]

**Normal phone:**

[image]